# UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I am create geopandas DataFrames and create a buffer to be able to do spatial joins. I set the `crs` for the DataFrame and then proceed to create buffers and encounter the warning then.

```
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['Long'], df1['Lat']))
# set crs for buffer calculations
df1.geometry.set_crs('EPSG:4326', inplace=True)

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2['Long'], df2['Lat']))
# set crs for buffer calculations
df2.geometry.set_crs('EPSG:4326', inplace=True)

# Returns a geoseries of geometries representing all points within a given distance
df1['geometry'] = df2.geometry.buffer(0.001)


/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_5601/4150826928.py:10: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

  df1['geometry'] = df2.geometry.buffer(0.001)
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/72073417/820534.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand `Geographic coordinate systems` and `Projected coordinate systems`.

Geographic CRS(such as 'EPSG:4326') is not suitable for measuring distance. Converting degree to distance requires additional work. Use a different coordinate as the warning message shows. The coordinates you usually use depend on the area you want to analyze.It will be common to use a coordinate system based on UTM.

Comment: We'll mostly be calculating distance within the United States.

Comment: And typically distance within 50m as we're looking for points in close proximity.

Comment: @kms I'm not sure what you mean. I'd like to recommend a specific coordinate system, but I don't know much about the United States. I searched and it seems that one of the coordinates of EPSG 26910 to 26919 can be used. Transform your coordinate system using gpd.GeoDataFrame.to_crs('EPSG:26910') and run the buffer.

Comment: Like what different coordinate system?

Answer (score 3):

Reproject your data to a coordinate system with meters as units using
[to_crs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html). Right now you are buffering with a distance of 0.001 degrees which means the distance will not be the same depending on where on earth you are.

```
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['Long'], df1['Lat']))
df1.geometry.set_crs('EPSG:4326', inplace=True)
df1['geometry'] = df1.geometry.to_crs("epsg:32633") #Change 32633 to a coordinate system which suits your data/requirements
```