# Limitations of coordinates transformations

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

In order to apply `shapely.affinity.scale` (see [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.scale)) I have had to transform a series of geodetic coordinates to projected coordinates, see [python - UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073417/) and [UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430138/) for context

All my coordinates are within a bounding box defined as 35.5, -11.0, 71.5, 31.5 (South, West, North, East) covering most of Europe.

Transformation of e.g. 54.1767° latitude and 7.8911° longitude from EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) to EPSG:4936 (ETRS89) results in [X: 3705858.6428144597 and Y: 513643.6629113175](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=4936&x=7.8911000&y=54.1767000). But the [reverse transformation](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4936&t_srs=4326&x=3705858.6428144597&y=513643.6629113175) results in 0° latitude and 7.8911° longitude! So something is wrong.

Transformation [from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3034 (ETRS89-extended / LCC Europe)](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3034&x=7.8911&y=54.1767) and [back to EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3034&t_srs=4326&x=3866814.6691679154&y=3036011.0450053057) works just fine.

Both coordinate systems (EPSG:4936 and EPSG:3034) cover the same area (WGS84 bounds: -16.1 32.88, 40.18 84.73) and the coordinates used fall within these bounds.

What limitation of coordinates transformations am I missing?

**UPDATE**: a Minimal, Reproducible Example in Python

```
In [1]: import geopandas as gpd 
        import pandas as pd 
        import shapely 

In [2]: point = shapely.Point([7.8911,54.1767]) 

In [3]: gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs="epsg:4326", 
                               geometry=[point]) 

In [4]: # transform point from WGS 84 to ETRS89 
        gdf["geometry"].to_crs(4936)
Out[4]: 0    POINT (3705858.64281 513643.66291)
        Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

In [5]: # transform point from WGS 84 to ETRS89 and back to WGS 84 
        gdf["geometry"].to_crs(4936).to_crs(4326) 
Out[5]: 0    POINT (7.89110 0.00000)
        Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

In [6]: # transform point from WGS 84 to ETRS89-extended 
        gdf["geometry"].to_crs(3034)
Out[6]: 0    POINT (3866814.669 3036011.045)
        Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

In [7]: # transform point from WGS 84 to ETRS89-extended and back to WGS 84 
        gdf["geometry"].to_crs(3034).to_crs(4326) 
Out[7]: 0    POINT (7.89110 54.17670)
        Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

Comment: simply all kinds of transformation come with some loss on accuracy, in particular when changing the so-called geodetic datum. Transforming twice will therefor double the error.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I understand that, but 54.34707° to 0° latitude is not a rounding error.

Comment: On the inverse the values need to be swapped. What you have labeled as X is the northing values and Y is the easting value.

Comment: @mkennedy I do not understand your comment. But I have simplified the MRE to make my original question easier to read. Which values exactly do you think need to be swapped?

Comment: OH, I should have checked the WKIDs. 4936 is the XYZ (3D geocentric/ECEF) version of ETRS89 so you should be printing 3 values for the output coordinates. I think dropping the 3rd value is what causes the very different results in the inverse calculation. I'd assumed 4936 was a UTM or GK projected CRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [EPSG:4326 (WGS 84)](https://epsg.io/4326) and [EPSG:3034 (ETRS89-extended / LCC Europe)](https://epsg.io/3034) are **2D** cartesian coordinate systems. [EPSG:4936 (ETRS89)](https://epsg.io/3034) is a (geocentric) **3D** cartesian coordinate system:

> Cartesian 3D CS (geocentric). Axes: geocentric X Y Z. Orientations: X and Y in equatorial plane, X positive through intersection with prime meridian, Y through 0°N 90°E. Z axis parallel to mean earth rotation axis and positive towards North Pole. UoM: m.

The transformation of coordinates into a 3D coordinate system requires three parameters. A missing parameter leads to an error during the transformation.

Thanks to [mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/963/mkennedy) for pointing me in the right direction!